# Non-measurable subset of $\omega_1$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Consider $\omega_1$ equipped with the order topology. Then Borel subsets of $\omega_1$ are precisely those which contain a closed and unbounded set or the complement contains such a set. There must be (in ZFC) sets which lack this property, as otherwise $\omega_1$ would be measurable. Can one please tell how to "construct" such sets (using some form of choice, of course).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A set $S\subseteq\omega_1$ is [*stationary*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_set) if it has non-empty intersection with every cub set, so it suffices to construct two disjoint stationary sets: neither can contain or be disjoint from any cub set. In fact [this post](http://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/580-cardinal-arithmetic-5/) from Andres Caicedo’s blog shows how to construct $\omega_1$ pairwise disjoint stationary subsets of $\omega_1$.

You may also find the two references in Joel David Hamkins’s answer to [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85646/a-stationary-set-of-successor-cardinal) helpful.

Comment: Is cub a variant I haven't seen, or do you mean club?

Comment: @Chris: The former; that’s how I learnt it.

Comment: Hi Brian, I abusively updated one of your links.

Comment: @Andres: Thanks; nothing like going to the source. (I think that I’ve pointed more people to your blog than to any other except Dan Ma’s topology blog.)

Answer (score 6):

It requires the axiom of choice, but there are sets which are stationary and co-stationary. Namely they do not contain a club not they a disjoint from one.

For example using Solovay's theorem we can partition $\omega_1$ into $\omega_1$ disjoint stationary sets.

In some models where the axiom if choice fails every subset of $\omega_1$ contains a club or is disjoint from one.